# menu bar control in flex ,needed to handle separate method for individual menu item

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

i need to fire separate method for individual menu item clicked ,so that individual item can handle separate method.

and i need know what all the properties are available in menu item like  type="radio".

```
<mx:MenuBar id="jj" labelField="@label" itemClick="MenuItemClick(event)" x="23" y="228">
    <mx:XMLList>
        <menuitem label="File">
            <menuitem label="New" type="radio"/>
            <menuitem label="Open" data="Openfile" type="Check" />
            <menuitem label="Save" />
            <menuitem label="Exist"/>
        </menuitem>           
    </mx:XMLList>   
</mx:MenuBar>
```

Can you give any link or example for menubar control?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Example from Adobe Flex docs [MenuBar](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/MenuBar.html)

Only three types allowed: check, radio, or separator.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- Simple example to demonstrate the MenuBar control. -->
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" creationComplete="initCollections();" >

    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

            import mx.events.MenuEvent;
            import mx.controls.Alert;
            import mx.collections.*;

            [Bindable]
            public var menuBarCollection:XMLListCollection;

            private var menubarXML:XMLList =
                <>
                    <menuitem label="Menu1" data="top">
                        <menuitem label="MenuItem 1-A" data="1A"/>
                        <menuitem label="MenuItem 1-B" data="1B"/>
                    </menuitem>
                    <menuitem label="Menu2" data="top">
                        <menuitem label="MenuItem 2-A" type="check"  data="2A"/>
                        <menuitem type="separator"/>
                        <menuitem label="MenuItem 2-B" >
                            <menuitem label="SubMenuItem 3-A" type="radio"
                                groupName="one" data="3A"/>
                            <menuitem label="SubMenuItem 3-B" type="radio"
                                groupName="one" data="3B"/>
                        </menuitem>
                    </menuitem>
                </>;

            // Event handler to initialize the MenuBar control.
            private function initCollections():void {
                menuBarCollection = new XMLListCollection(menubarXML);
            }

            // Event handler for the MenuBar control's itemClick event.
            private function menuHandler(event:MenuEvent):void  {
                // Don't open the Alert for a menu bar item that 
                // opens a popup submenu.
                if (event.item.@data != "top") {
                    Alert.show("Label: " + event.item.@label + "\n" + 
                        "Data: " + event.item.@data, "Clicked menu item");
                }        
            }
         ]]>
    </mx:Script>

    <mx:Panel title="MenuBar Control Example" height="75%" width="75%" 
        paddingTop="10" paddingLeft="10">

        <mx:Label width="100%" color="blue"
           text="Select a menu item."/>

        <mx:MenuBar labelField="@label" itemClick="menuHandler(event);" 
            dataProvider="{menuBarCollection}" />

    </mx:Panel>
</mx:Application>
```

Also bookmark this page [Language Reference](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/index.html).

Comment: hi. thnk u  for ur reply but i seen this example.. this example also call a single method(menuHandler) for all menuitem.....my requirement is to call separate method for individual menu item 

 <menuitem label="MenuItem 2-B" itemClick="somemethod();"  >

Comment: is it applicable in this control ?

Comment: There are no way to assign events to MenuBarItem-s because it can be loaded through dataProvider. Use Shua switch/case example.

Answer (score 0):

Vineth,

You are unable to add individual event handlers for menu items unless you dynamically create the menu bar and the sub items.  This is more pain than it's worth, so I would recommend using the itemCLick handler as stated above and use a switch to determine what methods to fire.  For example:

```
switch( event.item.@data ){

  case "3A":
    doSomething();
    break;
  case "3A":
    doSomethingElse();
    break;
  defualt:
    doDefault();
    break;

}
```

*Note: this is building off of zdmytriv answer*

Comment: hi,,thank u shua ... i am also doing in this way at present..  do u have example for dynamic creation of menu bar and the sub items and handling events ? 
even though it is overkill it will be better approach i think so... since instead of calling a method we are calling 2 methods so if u have that method provide me pls..  thanks again

Comment: hey,

I don't have a working example of this but this is what I've gathered after a quick look at the documentation.  My first approach would be to create instances of the MenuBarItem and simply add them to the menuBarItems array of the menuBar, but the live doc say you should not add items this way but rather update the menuBar dataProvider.  So instead you'll probably just have to loop through each item in the menuBarItems array and add the appropriate listeners.  However, I think zdmytriv answer is the best practice.  The number of methods called doesn't determine the better solution.